# What is Android Systems on LG Motion?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have KidLogger on my LG Motion. When I go to see what others have been doing on my phone, it says Android Systems. What is that, and where can I find it on my phone?

Comment: Keeping question open, since it can be answered.

Answer (score 2):

That's just the Android "Operating" System, like Windows / Linux system. If you go to `Settings > Battery`, you will see that "Android System", if not the "Screen", eats up most of your battery.